# Loading all classes as services in a specific path does not work

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, autowired

I'm totally new to "Dependency Injection" and I'm trying to implement the Dependency Injection component of the Symfony Framework into my application.

I've created a services.yaml as described in the manual. So it actually looks like the following:

```
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: true
  com\example\myapp\:
    resource: "../php/com/example/myapp"
```

My code:

```php
$container = new ContainerBuilder;

$loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator("/project/path/src/main/resources"));

$loader->load("services.yaml");

$container->get(SomeClass::class);// Throws ReflectionException
```

Whenever I try to get a service from the container, PHP throws an ReflectionException "Class  does not exist". I reverse engineered the component code a bit and realised that the class returned from Definition::getClass() is always null.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You need add `$container->compile();` before call to `$container->get();`

Comment: Oh, that did it! Thanks!